# The year counter is here

Tags: code-golf, date

Create a program that, given an integer N, outputs the number of years we have to get to N A.D. or how many years it has been since N A.D, as a string or int. For example, given 2014, the program should output 5 as it has been that many years since 2014. Input of the year in which you run the program should result in 0.

Treat the input "0" however you like: as its own year, as 1 A.D. or as 1 B.C. This means that you can pretend there IS a year zero and have all BC years be off by one.

Negative integers (integers with - in front of them) are treated as years B.C. For example inputting -2 would result in the program telling how many years it has been since 2 B.C.

Treat improper inputs (inputs that don't only use numbers and the dash as characters (abcd), or use the dash by itself or use it wrongly (e.g. 6-)) however you want, error or exit or something else.

The winning program is the program with the shortest code that does all of this. Have fun.

Comment: Am I dumb or has it been 5 years since 2014?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino it has

Comment: So an input of `-1` should result in an output of `2019` this year?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino maybe the thinking is that only 4 full calendar years have passed since the end of 2014. So what is the output meant to be for `2009`?..

Comment: @JonathanAllan If so, better question is what is the output for `2019`? Wouldn't be 0 in this case, but `-1` doesn't make sense, and neither does `1`...?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino agreed maybe there are three zero years

Comment: @JonathanAllan Hm. Well, OP posted and probably left, so hopefully they clarify, because otherwise I'm tempted to CV this because there are like three reasonable interpretations plus the answer of "OP forgot it was 2019"

Comment: My mistake about the years that it's been since 2014. 2019 should output 0.

Comment: Also I clarified. So there's that.

Comment: "Treat the input 0 however you like: as its own year, as 1 A.D. or as 1 B.C." - do you mean that even though there is no year zero we may pretend there was and have all B.C. years have an off by 1 error?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
žgα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70cxv//zcyMDQBAA)

**Explanation**

```
  α   # absolute difference between
      # implicit input
žg    # and current year
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 46 bytes

```java
n->(n-=java.time.Year.now().getValue())<0?-n:n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY5Bi8IwFITv/oqHpwRJ6IY9qdVfoBdhYVEPzxgltX0tzauLiL@9m8YeFvYyMDPwzRR4R1Wcb70tMQTYoKfnBMATu/aC1sF2sCkAKwYluYjJaxIlMLK3sAWCHHpSK0EqLyJRs6@c/nbYaqp/hNRXx19Ydk5IuczWiubUD5SmO5URMHLutT9DFR@IHbeervsjoHzPswssTPbxmcZHr8xfZzJj/l1LyFQP1z01HY/E3SOwq3TdsW7iGJckUj2bzg88nZG2by9H5qv/BQ)

Or alternatively:

```java
n->Math.abs(n-java.time.Year.now().getValue())
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCsIwEETvfsXiKUEaNHhS9A/qRRBEPawxamq7Lc1WEfHbaxp7ELwMzAy8mQzvmGSnW2ty9B5SdPQaADhiW5/RWFh1NgZgRKck5yF5D4J4RnYGVkCwgJaSZYp8VXj0gpIsgBW7wqqtxVpR@RBSXSxvMG@skLLtKFVzzAOg59xLd4IiPBBrrh1ddgdA@Z1n61no8WQax3uf6F@nx1r/XYvIWHfXHVUN98T107MtVNmwqsIY5yRiPRrO9jwckTJfL3vmu/0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
aKi
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YUtp&input=MjAxNA)

```
aKi     :Implicit input of year
a       :Absolute difference with
 K      :  Date
  i     :  Get year
```

Comment: lol, we posted the same answer at the same time. I deleted mine tho, i had another in php anyway

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz - technically, you got there first ... by 8 seconds! No need to delete either of them, though; it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
a.d3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1Evxfj/fyMDQxMA)

**Explanation:**

```
a.d3Q - full program. implicit Q added.
a     - absolute difference of
 .d3  - current year and
    Q - implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc) with `/u:System.Math` and `/u:System.DateTime` flags, <s>32</s> 18 bytes

```csharp
n=>Abs(Now.Year-n)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqMAJOwU0hRs/@fZ2jkmFWv45ZfrRaYmFunmaf635govyixJ9cnMS9VI0zAyMDTR1EQV0zVCFzEyMAKJ/f@XX1CSmZ9X/F@/1Cq4srgkNVfPN7EkA4nrkliSGpKZmwoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 22 bytes

```php
<?=date('Y')-$argv[1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUM9Ul1TVyWxKL0s2jDW@v///7qmAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
print(abs(int(input())-datetime.now().year))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chJbEktSQzN1UhM7cgv6hEi6ugKDOvRCMxqVgDRGfmFZSWaGhq6sLU6eXll2to6lWmJhZpav7/b2RgaAIA)

Gives 5 for 2014 because it's 2019, not 2018.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
a=>Math.abs(Date().split` `[3]-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1s43sSRDLzGpWMMlsSRVQ1OvuCAnsyRBISHaOFY3UfN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaRgaGJpqY1F4aoJaaorhE2lUamQNH/AA)

-6 bytes thanks to Luis felipe De jesus Munoz

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 30 bytes

```
func[y][absolute y - now/year]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85ujI2OjGpOD@ntCRVoVJBVyEvv1y/MjWxKPZ/QVFmXolCmoKRgaEJF4JjhOAY/AcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>131</s> 127 bytes

```cpp
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdio>
int main(){long y,t=time(0);scanf("%d",&y);y-=gmtime(&t)->tm_year+1900;printf("%d",y<0?-y:y);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJrkkMzfVjgvBLy5Jycy348rMK1HITczM09CszsnPS1eo1CmxBSnVMNC0Lk5OzEvTUFJNUdJRq9S0rtS1Tc8Fy6mVaOraleTGV6YmFmkbWhoYWBcUAQ2Cqq20MbDXrbQC6qj9/9/IwNAEAA)

Comment: Thanx for the hint, found an even better solution :)

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYvLCsIwEADv/QqpWBJsYCteatr4KRLWGgLmQbqXRfz2@ECPw8xgzsoh1rr1IadCE5IPi2n@6NNqmmB9FPJxT9FtuKf5kwiQekUbb6LdXdu@Y6lZzS58XUdSGQoXXmzZDyOAzsVH@rU8wVnx6X08az3AcHwB "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")